# How do I use the Chrome DevTools color picker tool instead of the vanilla Chrome color picker tool?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, color-picker

Google Chrome offers its own color picker tool developers can use when we don't want to install/write our own color picker to our website. It's useful. It's pretty. It's easy. Just insert a small, lovely line of HTML5

`<input type="color" />`

and it works. It's *almost* great. It's *almost* perfect. It's *almost* the bees' knees. *Almost*.

[image: An almost awesome color picker]

It's got rgb. It's got hex. It's even got hsl. But the dang thing doesn't allow users to change opacity. Which, is a little dumb. I want users to change the opacity, dang it!

Right now, users to my website can change the opacity. I'm lazy, so it's not crazy or anything. Just added a little bit more to the code up top, and it works. It's just not what I want.

`<input id="color" type="color"/><input id="opacity" type="number" min="0" max="1" />`

Obviously, Google can write a color picker tool which can use rgba and hsla. They did, and it's (still) in the current version of Google Chrome (91.0.4472.77). It's available in Google Chrome's DevTools. It's awesome. It's fantastic.

I want that color picker.
[image: The awesome color picker]

**Is there a way to use the awesome color picker on my website?**

*PS: I know I could write a color picker like that or install one I find on Github. But I don't want to do either of those two things because 1) I'm lazy and 2) Most of the ones I have tested look ugly and/or coded in such a way that I suddenly get a huge craving for pasta.*

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Are you asking if you can use Google's Color Picker on your website?  Or ?

Comment: I know I can use Google's Color Picker on my website. I want to know if I can use Google's DevTools Color Picker instead.

Comment: I am coding a website. This website has color pickers. How do I change my code to use the Chrome Dev Tools color picker? Is this even possible? Idk. Seemed like a coding question. Maybe it's not? I thought StackOverflow does a bit of these types of questions.

Comment: If that's your question, you need to show us the relevant code snippet.  Exactly what part of your code are you asking us about changing?  From what you've given us, we have no way to answer a question about changing code if you've not given us any code.  And the way your actual question reads, in its current form (and the answer below) -- it's asking about a tool.  Not about code modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place to look would be in the [Chrome Dev Tools API](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/). From what I can see, they just offer the [`Inspector`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Inspector/) as one monolithic unit which probably includes the color picker. But there is no hook for it independent of the `Inspector` that I see.

Perhaps if you added the [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-devtools-frontend) locally you could poke around and potentially find out how to use it. You can add the whole package as an npm dependency: `npm install chrome-devtools-frontend` or `yarn add chrome-devtools-frontend`.

Comment: I'll go take a look into the package and see if I can find a way. Thanks for the help (and the reassurance)! Thanks to you, I have a way forward to figuring this out. :)